# React Native Flatlist extracting

Tags: react-native, react-redux

A little inexperienced here. Trying to render data with React Native Flatlist.

Here is my data:

```
data = {
-LYIaWAxkQA38DAbC3By: {hours: "6", type: "Welding"}
-LYIab-Ys9WkUNHE2cqL: {hours: "2", type: "Hair Drying"
}
```

I am trying to use:

```
<FlatList 
  data=data
  renderItem={
    (item) => <Text>{item.type}</Text>
  } 
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

I want to be able to create a component that is able to use each type and hours.

I keep getting error, 'Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN'

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your data is not an array. That’s the problem. And using index as key is not meaningful for some cases. Use a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using an array**:

```
  const data = [
    {
       hours: "6", 
       type: "Welding",
       identifier: "-LYIaWAxkQA38DAbC3By",
       id: 1
    },
    {
       hours: "2", 
       type: "Hair Drying",
       identifier: "-LYIab-Ys9WkUNHE2cqL",
       id: 2
    }
  ]


  <FlatList 
    data=data
    renderItem={
    (item) => <Text>{item.type}</Text>
   }   
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using firebase? if yes, you can use forEach

```
componentDidMount(){
   this._convert();
  }

  _convert = () => {
   let ALL_DATA = this.state.data;
   let CONVERTED_DATA = [];

   ALL_DATA.forEach( (individu_Items) => {
   CONVERTED_DATA.push(individu_Items)
   }

    this.setState({flatlist_data: CONVERTED_DATA})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

transform your object in an array:

```
data = Object.keys(data).map((key) => data[key]));
```